# How to parse HTML or XHTML or XML with python in a efficient way?

Tags: python, html, xml, xhtml

My python env is 2.7

I know this is an old question, but I've lost my mind while I was searching and reading other people's questions and answers. Some of them is really out of date. Like the code below:

```
import lxml #wrong
import xml #correct
```

So, since I'm a newbie to python and know nothing whatsoever in the great python history, I wanna make things more clear to me. Such as, what is the so-called standard xml-parser module in python now? what can I do when I need parse some HTML by using the xpath syntax. If I have a mal-formed HTML source code, how can handle it by not using BeautifulSoup or something else like. If u can brief me with something, I'll be much appreciated.

OK, all in all, I just got one question. How can I parse mal-formed html code by using standard python module with python2.7?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use BeautifulSoup? It's the canonical answer to parsing malformed HTML in Python really.

Comment: alright, I think I need to do more research

Comment: seems like beautifulsoup do not support xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [python library documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/markup.html) if you need to stick to the standard library.

If you don't, definitely look at [lxml](http://lxml.de), which does much more.

Comment: python library documentation, u know, it doesn't contains much example, unlike the php manual

Comment: `HTMLParser` contains two whole sections which contain the word "Example" in their titles!